# How do I open and use pdftk?

Tags: lubuntu, pdftk

pdftk was installed using `sudo apt-get install pdftk` but how do I open and use this software?

Please help me find it and open it.

I have Lubuntu 14.0.

Comment: This question shows very little effort (to put it mildly).

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble remembering the command line syntax for the pdftk terminal program, you might get most of what you need from pdftk using PDF Chain (*pdfchain*). PDF Chain is a graphical user interface for the PDF Toolkit (*pdftk*). The package includes features designed to handle PDF files in a easy way. Basically it can merge, split, add backgrounds or stamps and add  attachments. There are some tools for extended needs too.

PDF Chain can be installed from the default Ubuntu 12.04-16.04 repositories or from the terminal with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install pdfchain
```